# VueJS doesn't re-render until loop is finished

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this piece of VueJS code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tiles: [
      { isActive: false },
      { isActive: false },
      { isActive: false },
      { isActive: false },
      { isActive: false }
    ]

  },
  methods: {
    startWithLoop: function() {
      console.log("startWithLoop");
      for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) { this.blink() };
    },
    startWithInterval: function() {
      console.log("startWithInteral");
      setInterval(this.blink);
    },
    blink: function(){
      console.log("blink");
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tiles.length);
      this.tiles[index].isActive = !this.tiles[index].isActive;
    }
  }
})
```

If I call the method `startWithInterval` I can see in the view how the `tiles` are changing state all the time.

If I call the method `startWithLoop` I don't see any change in the view until the loop is finished.

Here is [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/wc5jxvru/72/)

How can I trigger changes in the view on each step of the loop?

Comment: This is because your for loop is keeping the main thread busy: in that case, the browser do not have time between loops to update the DOM, so it defers the update until the for loop has completed.

Comment: Its todo with the stack, setInterval puts a function to be called on a stack whiles a for loop does not its not async, it just hangs till nextTick

Comment: You could use `$forceUpdate()`

Answer (score 2):

No, this is how Javascript eventloop works in browsers (and not only).

You can imagine that Javascript only gets executed in "gaps between moments", so that your picture of what happens in the browser is a still snapshot of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping up and as a merge of all the suggestions, I have understood that:

- In the middle of a JS loop VueJS is not gonna re-render anything

So you have to move the iterations of your loop to another process. I was thinking that *promises* can be a solution but an easier one is to use `setTimeout()` without the *delay* param.

So instead of this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) { 
  this.blink() 
};
```

My code would look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) { 
  setTimeout(this.blink)
}
```

Comment: It will be rare, but it's possible for this code to access the component after it has been destroyed. If the `setTimeout` is queued and the component is destroyed before the timeout triggers, `this.blink` will be called on the destroyed component. This is likely not going to cause problems, but that is why my code includes a `beforeDestroy` and code to keep a reference to the queued timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something loop-like that uses `setTimeout` to let changes be noticed by Vue and then pushed to the DOM.

```
beforeDestroy() {
  if (this.timeout != null) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = null;
  }
},
startWithLoop: function() {
  console.log("startWithLoop");
  let i = 0
  const iter = () => {
    this.blink();
    i += 1;
    if (i < 10000) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(iter);
    }
  }
  iter();
},
```

Working fiddle with the changes from above: https://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/9pqscat1/3/

Comment: Why to complicate that much the loop? is not this enough  `for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) { setTimeout(this.blink) };`?

Comment: Sure, you could remove that if you like. I added it because it was in your original code.

Comment: I wanted to offer a simplified version of your code, I was tented to edit your answer, but them I thought you may not like it. I have created a new answer taking your suggestion but simplifying the code to go directly to the point. Thanks